# EAV implementation on SIlverStripe ORM with polymorphic relations

Tags: orm, silverstripe, entity-attribute-value

I need to implement EAV and I'm hitched on polymorphic relation.

For example models are:

- ProductPage.
- Attribute.
- AttrValDecimal.
- AttrValBool.
- AttrValOtherType

How to create relations attribute-value and product-value correctly?

Every attribute can be one of few types: decimal, boolean, item from varchar list, few items from varchar list, etc...
so relations with value must be polymorphic.

I have already read this part of documentation
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/relations/#polymorphic-has-one
but still cant sort out how to implement EAV.

Comment: While Silverstripe would be a good platform for running the boilerplate for an EAV model, it doesn't have much out-of-the-box to help you.

Comment: I'd love to see this be a possibility, but I think it would require a fair amount of the core ORM to be replaced/overloaded to make it viable

Answer (score 1):

I'd to it the other way: have a has_one relation from the value objects back to attribute. Then add a Type enum to Attribute.

Your value tables will technically allow multiple values per attribute, but perhaps that's a feature you need?

The other, in retrospect probably better, way to handle this wood be to make BooleanAttribute a subclass of Attribute and let SilverStripe's multi-table inheritance do Bebe work for you.

You'll have to write your getters for value manually, and figure out which table to join to, but polymorphic has one isn't going to be any magic fix there - it's pretty simple.

Bigger picture I'd also challenge whether EAV is really what you need - it's going to create some really big queries and not be very good for searching. If searching doesn't matter and all need is flexible properties, maybe a JSON payload would be better?

Comment: Storing attributes as JSON breaks the 1NF rule. If you're happy to ignore that, I agree with storing your attribute data in JSON. You may like to consider leveraging Silverstripe's Config API and Cache, and optimizing any db query to either use a JSON data type (minimum MySQL 5.7 InnoDB, PostgreSQL 9.4, etc), or superficial JSON handling such as the https://github.com/phptek/silverstripe-jsontext module.

Comment: @Sam, thanks for your advice. I'll try your technics "multiple values per attribute". I really need EAV.  

Please, can you look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44778281/1638298 ?  Its strictly related to current one.